# How to configure child group using NettyServerCustomizer?

Tags: netty, httpserver, reactor-netty

I upgraded netty version and found out that TcpServer's bootstrap method had been removed from the version I had previously. I not able to figure out how to convert my existing code using new netty lib.

```
factory.addServerCustomizers((NettyServerCustomizer) httpServer -> {
                    httpServer
                    .tcpConfiguration(tcpServer ->
                            tcpServer
                                    .bootstrap(serverBootstrap ->
                                            serverBootstrap
                                                    .group(parentGroup, childGroup)
                                                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                                    )
                    );
```

I can do `httpServer.runOn(parentGroup)` but can't figure out how to configure childGroup with that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below as a replacement:

```
LoopResources loop =
         new LoopResources() {
             @Override
             public EventLoopGroup onServer(boolean useNative) {
                 return childGroup;
             }

             @Override
             public EventLoopGroup onServerSelect(boolean useNative) {
                 return parentGroup;
             }
         };

httpServer.runOn(loop, false);
```

This is if you want to use some specific implementation for the `EventLoopGroup`.

If your requirement is just to use NIO then you can use the code below:

```
LoopResources loop = LoopResources.create("my-loop", parentGroupNumThreads, childGroupNumThreads, true);

server.runOn(loop, false);
```